# use IMemoryCache in AuthorizationFilter class

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

how to add IMemoryCache in dependency injection i want to use this but when i add this in my code like below its show me error in startup.cs file how to add paramter of IMemoryCache in Startup.cs
Startup.cs error

> Error CS0542  'HMACAuthenticationAttribute': member names cannot be the
>   same as their enclosing type

```
  public class HMACAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
     private IMemoryCache _cache;
              public HMACAuthenticationAttribute(IMemoryCache cache)
                    {
                        _cache = cache;
                    }
   }


     services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new HMACAuthenticationAttribute())).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Comment: The only way you'd get that error is if you have a field or property on this class named `HMACAuthenticationAttribute`. The posted code does not have such a member, so I can only assume you've redacted part of your code, which of course then obscures where the problem lies. Post the real code, or simply just read what the exception is telling you and fix it. This is pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, you cannot inject into attributes. However, you're not *actually* using this as an attribute, so it's fine. As a result, you should not inherit from `Attribute`, since it's both unnecessary and misleading: if you ever actually *do* use this as an attribute, it will fail, because `_cache` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

> how to add IMemoryCache in dependency injection

You could register `IMemoryCache` instance to DI pipeline with `services.AddMemoryCache();` in `ConfigureServices()` method in Startup.cs class. This should solve your problem. For more information check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.0) official Microsoft page.